# how to get the logs of integrated command of find and mv?

Tags: find, logs, mv, hp-ux

I used this command to my script to find specific files and to moved to different folder; however, I would need to generate a log of which file/s I have moved.

```
find $1* -prune -name "*.$2" -mtime +$3 -exec mv {} $4 \;
```

What to add to that command to be able to generate a log?

Comment: Does your `mv` command have a `-v` (`--verbose`) option?

Comment: Hi Steeldriver,  here is the command in my script: find $1* -prune -name "*.$2" -mtime +$3 -exec mv {} $4 \; , where will i insert the verbose option?

Comment: @steeldriver HP-UX's `mv` does not have `-v` as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3):

Your command,

```
find $1* -prune -name "*.$2" -mtime +$3 -exec mv {} $4 \;
```

should, first of all, be written as

```
find "$1"* -prune -name "*.$2" -mtime +"$3" -exec mv {} "$4" \;
```

otherwise you disqualify it from being used on directories and files with spaces in their names.

To output the pathnames of the things actually moved by the `mv` in this command, simply add `-print` last:

```
find "$1"* -prune -name "*.$2" -mtime +"$3" -exec mv {} "$4" \; -print
```

This would output the pathnames of all files (or directories) that were successfully moved to the destination given by `"$4"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add another `-exec` block with an `echo` command to write to a log file, i.e.

```
find $1* -prune -name "*.$2" -mtime +$3 -exec mv {} $4 \; -exec echo mv {} $4 >> /path/to/log \;
```

If you want less information, just modify the final `-exec` block, e.g. `-exec echo {} >> /path/to/log \;`

#### Error logging

If you also want to log whether the command was successful or not, you could also pipe the standard error from the `mv` command to the log file. I don't think it's guaranteed that the first `-exec` necessarily acts first, so I would use one `-exec` in this case. N.B. the syntax gets a bit fiddlier here.

```
find $1* -prune -name "*.$2" -mtime +$3 -exec mv {} $4 \; -exec sh -c 'echo mv $1 $2 >> /path/to/log; mv $1 $2 2>> /path/to/log' . {} $4 \;
```

#### Some comments

I'm not sure of your exact use case, but it's good practice to quote your variables, e.g. `find "$1"* …`, in case there are filenames with spaces/etc. in them.

Secondly, `-execdir` is preferred over `-exec`. From `man find`:

> There are unavoidable security problems surrounding use of the -exec action; you should use the -execdir option instead.

#### mv -v instead

Alternatively, as per steeldriver's [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501497/how-to-get-the-of-integrated-command-of-find-and-mv/501498?noredirect=1#comment924244_501497), if your version of `mv` supports the verbose `-v` option, you could modify the original `-exec` block instead, to

```
-exec mv -v {} $4 >> /path/to/log \;
```

which will provide output similar to `renamed 'foo' -> 'bar'`.

Comment: Hi Sparhawk,  just tried, and it just log the action, but it didn't action (it didn't move the files)

Comment: @GerardSacay That's really odd. The rest is the same as your original command. Were there any errors?

Comment: @GerardSacay You probably just added the `echo`, without reading the full command. He now has two `-exec` bits. You need both.

Comment: No comment on the lack of quoting, @Sparhawk?

Comment: @Kusalananda TBH I find the whole command a bit strange. I'm not entirely sure what the `*`s are doing in there, so I just tried to be agnostic about it all.

Comment: They're using it with `$1*` being a pattern matching a set of _files_. The `-prune` is simply making sure it's not recursing into subdirectories. They have no `-maxdepth` predicate.

Comment: @Kusalananda I guess I'm saying that because I don't totally understand the use case, I presumed that quoting is not necessary. Probably that's too naive of me though. I edited to mention it, and also added some error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a -print before the -exec to have the filename printed before moved.

Comment: Adding `-print` _before_ the `-exec` would print the pathnames that the command _tried_ to move, not the pathnames that were successfully moved.

Comment: Good point. It should of course go after the exec.